# why i am getting 3 7 as output even if i am using break statement /* 4 4 2 2 4 3 */ /* o/p 1 2 3 7 */

Tags: c++, search

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
//program to find index of number giving sum as m
int main() {
    int m;
    cin>>m;    //sum
    int n;         //size of array
    cin>>n;
    int a[n];
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    int k=1;
    while(k<=n) {
        for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            if(a[k] + a[k+i]==m) {
                cout<<k<<" "<<k+i<<"\n";    //printing index of numbers giving sum as m
                break;
            }
        }
        k++;
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

/*
i/p
4
4
2 2 4 3
*/

/*
o/p
1 2
3 7
*/

why i am getting 3 7 as output even if i am using break statement /*i/p 4 4 2 2 4 3 */  /* o/p 1 2  3 7  */

Comment: You have multiple problems... It starts with you using [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), which are not part of the C++ language. Then you continue to use one-based indexing, arrays in C++ are zero-based. And you then go out of bounds of the array you created.

Comment: `int a[n];` is not C++.  Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude TBF, g++ does have support for VLA:s

Comment: It seems like you would need a good book about C++. This is now how you write C++ code

Comment: Oh, and [don't include `<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h). And [`using namespace std;` is a bad habit as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). It seems you use a so-called "competition" site to learn how to use C++, and they're really bad as tutors and learning resources (unless all you want to learn are bad habits and bad code). Get [a few good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) or take classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ array indexes start at zero not one, so

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    cin>>a[i];
}
```

Similarly here, but also because you access the array at index `k+1` you need to compare this against `n` rather than `k`.

```
int k=0;
while(k+1<n) {
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(a[k] + a[k+i]==m) {
            cout<<k<<" "<<k+i<<"\n";    //printing index of numbers giving sum as m
            break;
        }
    }
    k++;
    
}
```

Any array accesses that are out of bounds give your whole program *undefined behaviour* meaning anything is possible when you run the program.

Plus you are using *variable length arrays* `int a[n];` which are not legal C++. In C++ array bounds must be compile time constants.

Comment: There is also an out of band access here: `a[k+i] `. Better to use `a[i]` and start `i` at `k+1`